# .common-parent hover effect in HTML

Tags: html, css, github

I'm relatively new to coding, and working on a repo in Github. I have 12 clickBoxes on the same page that I'm applying a hover effect to, so that a PNG appears on hover. When the hover effect is applied, the clickBox no longer works, and vice versa. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with HTML

The clickBox I'm currently working on is .clickBox-Ministries. This is the hover effect in CSS:

```
.clickBox-Ministries,
.png-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 6%;
    height: 14%;
    top: 12%;
    left: 11%;
}
.png-overlay{
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 12%;
    height: 13%;
    top: 12.5%;
    left: 8%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
.common-parent{
    position: relative;
}
img.png-overlay:hover{
    display: inline;
    opacity: 1;
    /*transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When I set up the HTML this way, the clickBox doesn't work and neither does the hover effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main Nav -->
        <div class=clickContainer>
            <div class="common-parent">
                <div class="clickBox-Ministries">

                </div>
                <img class="png-overlay" src="Ministries_Overlay.png">
            </div>
```

When I remove the closing tag from the .common-parent, the PNG hover effect works but the clickBox does not.

Finally, when I remove the closing tag from .clickBox-Ministries, the clickBox works but the PNG hover effect does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main Nav -->
        <div class=clickContainer>
            <div class="common-parent">
                <div class="clickBox-Ministries">
                <img class="png-overlay" src="Ministries_Overlay.png">
            </div>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your clickBox-Ministries div has no height because it has no content - except when you leave off its terminating /div,  in which case it thinks the img is its content and takes on the image's natural height.

By default, div elements are block level elements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements for discussion on how they pick up their default width and height.

One way to check what is happening is to inspect the elements via your browser's dev tools. You'll see in your example that the div takes on the width of the viewport (possibly minus a bit for default margin, depending on what you have box-sizing set as) and height of 0 unless it has the img within it.

On a more minor point, to make the image fade out gradually in the same way as it fades in, put the transition on the img class, not on just the hover.

Here is a snippet which does these alterations. It's a bit strange because without any natural height to the clickable div it's only the img that does anything (on hover in that case). If  you want the div above the img to be clickable it needs some clickable area, i.e. some content or to have height and width explicitly set.

So when you run this snippet you get a blank page and have to sort of wave the mouse around near the top left to get the img to appear.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.clickContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.clickBox-Ministries,
.png-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 6%;
    height: 14%;
    top: 12%;
    left: 11%;
}
.png-overlay{
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 12%;
    height: 13%;
    top: 12.5%;
    left: 8%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.common-parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img.png-overlay:hover{
    display: inline;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Main Nav -->
        <div class=clickContainer>
            <div class="common-parent">
                <div class="clickBox-Ministries">
                </div>
                <img class="png-overlay" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
            </div>
         </div>
```